# Publishing policy through Wso2 EntitlementPolicyAdminService

Tags: soap, wso2, policies, wso2-identity-server

So i am trying to add some policies to the PDP of wso2. I did manage to add policies using this code

```
 public function addPolicy($policy, $policyId = '')
    {
        $this->soapClient->__soapCall(
            'addPolicy',
            [
                'parameters' => [
                    'policyDTO' => [
                        'policyId' => $policyId,
                        'policy' => $policy
                        ]
                    ]
            ]
        );
    }
```

Then i want to publish the policy i just added to the PDP using this code

```
public function publishPolicy($policyId)
    {
        $this->soapClient->__soapCall(
            'publishToPDP',
            [
                'parameters' => [
                    'verificationCode' => $policyId,
                    'enabled' => true,
                    'order' => 1
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
```

However the policy is not published to PDP. The server seems to receive the request but do nothing. Am i doing something wrong? How should this request be formed?

I have also tried the `publishPolicies` SoapCall but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that the `publishToPDP` is not really active. What actually worked is using the `addPolicy` with some additional attributes like `promote`.

Here is an example of how it worked for me

```
$this->soapClient->__soapCall(
            'addPolicy',
            [
                'parameters' => [
                    'policyDTO' => [
                        'policyId' => $policyId,
                        'policy' => $policy,
                        'version' => $version,
                        'policyOrder' => $policyOrder,
                        'active' =>  true,
                        'promote' => true
                        ]
                    ]
            ]
        );
```

Using these attributes the policy is added and is published to PDP.